# When I start my PC sometimes it doesn't log me on

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen, lock, pin

Hello to the SuperUser community,

I have recently installed Windows 10 Education on a Dell Precision laptop. It is on the latest, stable Fall Creators Update build (1709).

In recent days I have encountered an intermittent issue where when I boot the laptop and dismiss the lock screen to log on, the login screen does not appear. I see only my lock screen background fade (as it does on the login screen), but I do not see my user name and the password field. I wait about 30 seconds and then my PC returns to the lock screen. I keep dismissing it and seeing nothing for 30 seconds before the lock screen reappears.

On some other occasions I do get the login screen, but after logging it the page hangs on "Welcome" for about 30 seconds and then the lock screen reappears. When I dismiss it I have to log on again. Whether I see the login screen or not, I found that restarting the PC would solve the problem in most cases.

Furthermore, I have set up a PIN on my laptop through Windows Settings but do not see this option under Sign-up options, only for my Microsoft Account password and the recovery options I set on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation is damaged.

Please run the following command as Admin:

**sfc /scannow**

**Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**

If it cannot resolve the issue, using the official ISO file to perform an In-Place Upgrade installation.

For logon and logoff immediately issue, refer to this Microsoft office document resolution:

Windows Log on and Log off immediately.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/555648

Comment: The two command prompts above return no errors, i.e. the messages say "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations" and "The restore operation completed successfully. The operation completed successfully", respectively. Of note is that my PC was originally delivered to me with Windows 10 Home installed and I upgraded to Windows 10 Education by entering a new product key in Settings. Because of this, I do not have any access to the official ISO file as mentioned in your post. I see an option in Settings to reset my PC without losing my personal files so I will try that.